# Dart - Changing Json Map dynamically

Tags: json, dictionary, dart

I need to modify a json (Map<String, dynamic>). Need to update values, add new values, etc.
But the problem is: If the new value I'm trying to add (or update), is not of the same type of actual value or String, it throws an Exception......

Is there a way to insert or modify a json with new types of values???

***(In C# with newtonsoft json, or in NodeJs, I am able to do it easyly)***

This is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> _json = {
    'key 1': 'value 1',
    'key 2': 'value 2',
    'key 3': {
      'key 3_1': {
        'key 3_1_1': 'value 3.1.1'
      }
    },
    'key 4': {
      'key 4.1': {
        'key 4.1.1': 'value 4.1.1'
      }
    },
    'key 5': 4,
    'key 6': true
  };
  
  (_json['key 3']['key 3_1'] as Map<String, dynamic>).update('key 3_1_1', (v) => '4'); // <---- this works
  (_json['key 3']['key 3_1'] as Map<String, dynamic>).update('key 3_1_1', (v) => 4); // <--- this does not work
  (_json['key 3']['key 3_1'] as Map<String, dynamic>).putIfAbsent('key 3_1_2', () => 4); // <--- this does not work too
  (_json['key 3']['key 3_1'] as Map<String, dynamic>).putIfAbsent('key 3_1_2', () => {'a': '4'}); // <--- this does not work
  print(_json);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your original "JSON" map literals are typed.
For example, the subexpression

```dart
      {
        'key 3_1_1': 'value 3.1.1'
      }
```

has type `Map<String, String>` because that's the apparent type of the elements, and there is no context type overriding it (the context type is just `dynamic`, if anything).

If you wrote the original code as:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> _json = {
    'key 1': 'value 1',
    'key 2': 'value 2',
    'key 3': <String, dynamic>{
      'key 3_1': <String, dynamic>{
        'key 3_1_1': 'value 3.1.1'
      }
    },
    'key 4': <String, dynamic>{
      'key 4.1': <String, dynamic>{
        'key 4.1.1': 'value 4.1.1'
      }
    },
    'key 5': 4,
    'key 6': true
  };
```

you would get the same effect as JSON-encoding and then decoding (and much more efficiently).

Comment: Where did you learn this? I didn't even know it was possible to write a json like this inside Dart!
Anyway, you nailed it, it works like a charm!

Comment: The code isn't JSON. It's Dart code which produces Dart `Map` objects with a structure which mimics the structure of JSON. JSON is a text format, not a run-time data format, so you convert between JSON source and language-native runtime representation in every language which works with JSON (JavaScript possibly excepted).
The Dart JSON encoder will encode any map with `String` keys, it decodes JSON into `Map<String, dynamic>` maps.
What happens here is that you want to do Dart operations on the Dart map before converting to JSON, and then you need to respect the Dart type system too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it!

Just need to import dart:convert and add this line BEFORE any json operations:

```
_json = json.decode(json.encode(_json));
```

I don't know why but converting json inline is different from creating a new json using convert..